# Solved - MongoDB Server not connecting - MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, localhost, mongodb-compass

**Solution Provided in the End**

This is my *app.js* code

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB");

const itemsSchema = {
    name: String,
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
    name: "Drink Water",
});

const item2 = new Item({
    name: "Go for a run",
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2];

// Item.insertMany(defaultItems)

const listSchema = {
    name: String,
    items: [itemsSchema],
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

app.get("/", async function (req, res) {
    let allItems;
    try {
        allItems = await Item.find();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(allItems);
    return res.render("i");
});

app.post("/", async function (req, res) {
    let item = new Item({
        name: req.body.newItem.trim(),
    });
    let listName = req.body.list;
    if(listName === "today"){
        item.save();
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
    let foundList = await List.findOne({name: listName}).exec();
    foundList.items.push(item);
    foundList.save();
    return res.redirect("/"+listName);
});

app.post("/delete", async function (req, res) {
    let id = req.body.checkbox;
    let listName = req.body.listName.toLowerCase();
    if(listName === "today"){
        try {
            const item = await Item.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
    let foundList = await List.findOne({name: listName}).exec();
    foundList.items.pull({_id: id});
    foundList.save();
    return res.redirect("/"+listName);
});

app.get("/:listName", async function (req, res) {
    let { listName } = req.params;
    if(listName.toLowerCase() == "delete"){
        return res.redirect("/");
    }

    let foundList = await List.findOne({name: listName.toLowerCase()}).exec();

    if(!foundList){
        const list = new List({
            name: listName,
            items: [],
        });  
        list.save();
        foundList = list;
    }

    return res.render("list", {
        listTitle: listName,
        items: foundList.items,
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

This is my *package.json* code

```json
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Node and npm version:

```bash
node -v
v18.16.1

npm -v
8.13.2
```

There was absolutely no problem connection to localhost mongodb, **until** I tested one of my apps on **Atlas cluster**, and updated node.js to v18.16.1. Now the connection gets established and the code works perfectly fine when using Atlas cluster, **but it is not working for localhost anymore**.

I'm using nodemon so I can also continuously track errors.
Initially I'm getting the following error when starting *localhost:3000: on my browser:

```bash
MongooseError: Operation `items.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
undefined
D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `lists.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

When I modified the code to write something to the database instead of reading with `Item.find()` in `app.get("/")`, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3237
        for (let i = 0; i < error.writeErrors.length; ++i) {
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3237:47
```

I tried console logging the mongodb connection status using `console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)` and its giving the value `2` which meaning *Connecting*.

After waiting for a while without exiting the nodemon terminal, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 20551391,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\to-do-list\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

I have tried starting the mongodb server both from Compass and mongosh.

[image: MongoDB Compass]

When I tried checking which app/services are using the port "27017", I found all the PID mentioned point to Compass only:

[image: Check port usage]

[image: port 27100]

[image: port 26840]

[image: port 28668]

Even telnet on localhost 27017 was successful

[image]

[image]

I have tried:

- Deleting the node_modules package and *.json files, and reinstalling all dependencies.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling mongodb.
- Restarting Compass.
- Restarting system.
- Starting server from Compass
- Starting server from mongosh

The main problem here seems to be MongoDB not connecting or refusing to connect: `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`, as timeout and other errors won't even occur if it had been successfully connected.

Please help me fix this the error

### Soution

The problem turned out to be localhost using ipv6 address, and MongoDB running on ipv4.

Some solutions that I found are:

- Adding a `family: 4` option as `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB",{family: 4});`. This tells the localhost to use ipv4.
- Running `mongod --ipv6` on terminal. Localhost uses ipv6 so this `--ipv6` enables ipv6 access for mongodb.
- Replacing `localhost` in `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB");` with `127.0.0.1` ad `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB");`. `127.0.0.1` is the localhost ipv4 address. `::1` is the localhost ipv6 address
- Use *node v16*